# Or condition in bash pattern

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I'm searching some files with: `find . -name "*.en.php"` and `find . -name "*.fr.php"`.

I want both commands in the same line, something like : `find . -name "*.(en|fr).php"` but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

my command is like this : `find . -not -path Config -name "*.fr.php"`, is there a solution do not repeat `-not -path Config` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
find -name "*.en.php" -o -name "*.fr.php"
```

If you for example want to run command on each found file, than you need to additional `()`
(this will count num of lines in all found files):

```
find \( -name "*.en.php" -o . -name "*.fr.php" \) -exec cat {} \; | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `find` `-o` operator, eg.

```
find . -name "*.en.php" -o -name "*.fr.php"
```

Edit:

Like so:

```
find . -path './Config' -prune -o \( -name "*.en.php" -o -name "*.fr.php" \)
```

The default operator in find (if one is ommited) is `and`, the parentheses group the name expression. I've added `-prune` to prevent find from recursing into the Config directory.

Comment: thanks, but it's not working, i get it with `find ./^Config  \( -name "*.fr.php" -o -name "*.en.php" \)`

Comment: @jules: I messed up `-path`, also note that `-path` expects a full pathname, perhaps you want to use in conjunction with `-prune`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to combine expression with an `or` operator, thus:

```
find . -name '*.en.php' -o -name '*.fr.php' ...
```

You can see all the operators in the `man` page listed under `OPERATORS` (`and`, `or`, `not`, parentheses and so forth).